# logoff active directory users with multiple sessions

Tags: powershell, session, authentication, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

Currently we are trying to make a script in Powershell in a Windows Server 2008 R2 domain that logs off any user that has two active sessions, what we are trying to accomplish is to log off the user from the second session the moment he makes the Login

Here is the Script

```
$ScriptUsers = "x", "y"
$MaxSessions = 1
$Sessions = 0;
$LogoffCommand = $env:systemroot + "\system32\logoff.exe"

$TSServers = Get-ADComputer -Filter *

 foreach ($Server in $TSServers.ServerName)
 { 
  $CurrentUser = $env:username.Trim()

  if ($ScriptUsers -inotcontains $CurrentUser)
  {
    return
  }

$WmiUserNameExpression = "*,Name=`"" + $CurrentUser + "`""
$Sessions = $Sessions + get-wmiobject Win32_LoggedOnUser | `
select Antecedent | `
where { $_.Antecedent -ilike $WmiUserNameExpression } | `
measure-object

if ($Sessions.Count -gt $MaxSessions)
  {
   &$LogoffCommand
   $Sessions = $Sessions-1;
  }
 }
```

However it seems to take only sessions in a local computer, not in the Domain, how can we fix this in order to monitor every session in the domain and logoff any other concurrent session? Also, how can we pass as a parameter the number of sessions that the user has on Domain PCs?

Comment: you could query the sessions from other computers via wmi like you are doing on the local machine but that might take a long time depending on the number of machines^^ or you could try `query user` you will have to do some performance testing though^^ as far as i am aware there is no central place where you could get all sessions for a specific user across multiple machines

Comment: hmm another idea: if you change the logonscript to for example create a file on a share specific to the username (containing the machine name) and delete it via logoff script then you could check in logon if a file is allready present and react accordingly. This approach will be much faster performance wise but you would have to test how stable it works since the potential for errors is fairly large imho. one way to circumvent some of the error cases would be to query the machine from the file before reacting so you dont falsely shut the user off (just brainstorming atm forgive the spam :D)

Comment: No worries Paul, I am right now checking the query user, however, in the /server command it seems to allow only one server, meaning that the command will underperform on the domain since there would be no need for the ´return´ clause, also the specific file could be deleted by the user, and that is something we would like to avoid if possible
If only I could make that command a bit more efficient or try to get an unique code for that specific need....

Comment: you could run the query command asynchronously to increase performance but i think the log to share is best performance wise. You can give users only read/write and make it a hidden share, that way users cant delete or modify the log

Comment: here is a thread where someone actually had a similar idea as me, maybe you can find some inspiration or security considerations there: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/82-monitor-user-log-in-and-log-off-without-software